# How to fix ·libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" module dependencies?

Tags: android, linux, rust, compilation, android-source

Im trying to run AOSP and I give an error libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu dependencies.

Could yo helpme regarding where I can download the module dependencie?

```
root@german-VirtualBox:/home/german/WORK_DIR/out# cat error.log
FAILED: out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
Outputs: out/soong/build.ninja
Error: exited with code: 1
Command: cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used Android.bp
Output:
error: external/rust/crates/memchr/Android.bp:41:1: "libmemchr" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/pin-project-lite/Android.bp:42:1: "libpin_project_lite" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/proc-macro-hack/Android.bp:41:1: "libproc_macro_hack" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/rustversion/Android.bp:40:1: "librustversion" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/proc-macro-nested/Android.bp:49:1: "libproc_macro_nested" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The **libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu**  lib is available in https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:prebuilts/rust/linux-x86/1.58.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/

This lib will be downloaded as part of AOSP code in prebuilts/rust.git.
Try syncing this project again

```
repo sync prebuilts/rust
```

The sync was failing for me with below error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function
```

After installing gnutls-bin package it synced successfully.

```
apt install gnutls-bin
```