# I got this error while building AOSP 12.1

Tags: android-source

I got this error while building AOSP 12.1

it is aosp 12.1_r1, how can I fix it?
It is based on AOSP, and I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with 32 GB Ram

```
error: external/rust/crates/ppv-lite86/Android.bp:39:1: "libppv_lite86" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/futures-task/Android.bp:67:1: "libfutures_task" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/pin-project-lite/Android.bp:42:1: "libpin_project_lite" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/unicode-segmentation/Android.bp:42:1: "libunicode_segmentation" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: prebuilts/rust/Android.bp:343:1: "libunicode_width.rust_toolchain" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/managed/Android.bp:54:1: "managed_host_test_src_lib" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/shlex/Android.bp:40:1: "libshlex" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/rustc-hash/Android.bp:39:1: "librustc_hash" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/shlex/Android.bp:47:1: "shlex_host_test_src_lib" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/rustversion/Android.bp:40:1: "librustversion" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/scopeguard/Android.bp:39:1: "libscopeguard" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/bencher/Android.bp:59:1: "libbencher" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/futures-io/Android.bp:66:1: "libfutures_io" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/itoa/Android.bp:41:1: "libitoa" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/lazycell/Android.bp:39:1: "liblazycell" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/proc-macro-hack/Android.bp:41:1: "libproc_macro_hack" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/fallible-streaming-iterator/Android.bp:64:1: "libfallible_streaming_iterator" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/proc-macro-nested/Android.bp:49:1: "libproc_macro_nested" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/cfg-if/Android.bp:87:1: "libcfg_if" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/rustc-hash/Android.bp:64:1: "rustc-hash_host_test_src_lib" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/untrusted/Android.bp:45:1: "untrusted_host_test_src_untrusted" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/ryu/Android.bp:42:1: "libryu" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/regex-syntax/Android.bp:41:1: "libregex_syntax" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/libm/Android.bp:41:1: "liblibm" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/unicode-width/Android.bp:40:1: "libunicode_width" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/untrusted/Android.bp:21:1: "libuntrusted" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
error: external/rust/crates/matches/Android.bp:45:1: "matches_host_test_lib" depends on undefined module "libtest_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
13:02:48 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

github.com/PixelExperiencePad/manifest/tree/twelve-pad > This is my manifest for 12L(12.1), which is based on PE and modded to use SP2A(12.1) Source, is it where the problem originate? If so, can you tell me what parts to fix?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68436057/how-to-fix-libtest-x86-64-unknown-linux-gnu-module-dependencies) answer your question?

Comment: @Alexandru Placinta I tried his method but it still isn;t working. Thanks for your replay anyway. https://github.com/PixelExperiencePad/manifest/tree/twelve-pad > This is my manifest for 12L(12.1), which is based on PE and modded to use SP2A(12.1) Source, is it where the problem originate? If so, can you tell me what parts to fix?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error.
I fixed it by replacing the build/soong directory. build/soong directory picked from another rom (xdroidoss)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Loki I got  unrecognized property "multilib.lib32.product_variables.malloc_not_svelte_libc32" this time, do you know a fix? Thanks.

Comment: who modded the manifest ?